# How can I get all the devices from database table whose RAM is in between 1 MB to 2 GB?

Tags: mysql

I am storing the value in MySql table as below:

```
id        content_id   group_id   value
================================================
12274     251          5          4 GB, 512 MB RAM
12323     252          5          32 GB, 2 GB RAM
12372     253          5          8 GB, 2 GB RAM
12421     254          5          8 GB, 1 GB RAM
12470     255          5          8 GB, 1 GB RAM
12519     256          5          4 GB, 512 MB RAM
```

Where value column contain internal memory and RAM of the mobile clubbed with comma in each row, Now I want to perform search result on value column which gives me all the rows between RAM "512 MB" AND "2 GB"

How i can perform this action in MySql? Please help

Comment: I need to get the result without updating its structure.

Comment: You should really push back on it. Updating the structure once is likely to be a lot saner than what this query is going to look like (and how fast it'll run). That's not a reason not to answer the question as posed (I hope somebody does) but I can't stress that enough for your real-world situation.

Comment: *"I need to get the result without updating its structure"* See mine (updated) answer and approach

Answer (score 4):

This started off as a comment, but then exceeded the available space.  We could give you a query for this, but it would bloated and ugly.  It would be much better for you to fix your table design to something like this:

```
id        content_id   group_id   value_low   value_high
=========================================================
12274     251          5          0.512       4
12323     252          5          2           32
12372     253          5          2           8
12421     254          5          1           8
12470     255          5          1           8
12519     256          5          0.512       4
```

The key points here to appreciate are first that we have separate bona fide columns for the low and high parts of the memory range.  Second, we are using a consistent unit, GB, everywhere.  With these changes in mind, we can easily write your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE value_high >= 2.0 AND value_low <= 0.512;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for quick reply but its difficult for me to update the table structure coz the project is too old and have thousands of entries.

Comment: Absolute case study in not making design mistakes (read: taking shortcuts) like this at the beginning, because now it's really difficult for you to work around it yet the data is stored in a totally inappropriate manner. Condolences!

Comment: I'd actually store bytes and keep it all fixed point (in fact, integral). Floating point gigabytes has plenty of potential issues.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Correct me if I'm wrong, but MySQL integers would only cover up to about 4GB.  We should really use double here.

Comment: Agreed, but the project is started with someone else, I am here to add new features,  I can only find workaround, Updating the structure is completely out of my scope.

Comment: Then use `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. 2^64-1 delicious max value. How much RAM do you have? :D Floating-point should be only used as a last resort, not just because you [think you] need more range. Other options include doing kilobytes or even megabytes instead (reasonable in this particular context). But decimal gigabytes bad

Comment: As an aside, "I can only find workaround" is exactly the sort of management mentality that caused this problem in the first place. Your bosses are just creating more and more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Comma separated values are hard to query. 
Tricky SQL is needed to parse the items into records so ideally you should normalize like Tim Biegeleisen suggested.

Also when you have MySQL 8.0 using a regex is most likely more easier.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  #remove duplicates
  DISTINCT 
      t.*
    , TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.value, ',', numbers.number), ',', -1)) AS tag
    , CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('GB', UPPER(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.value, ',', numbers.number), ',', -1)))) > 0
        # return GB to MB calculated                                               
        THEN (TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.value, ',', numbers.number), ',', -1)) + 0.00) * 1024
        # return MB value                                  
        ELSE TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.value, ',', numbers.number), ',', -1)) + 0.00                        
      END AS MB_calculated                                                
FROM (

  SELECT
    @number := @number + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) row1
     CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) row2
     CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT @number:=0) AS init_user_params
  )  
) 
 AS numbers
CROSS JOIN t
WHERE 
  CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('GB', UPPER(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.value, ',', numbers.number), ',', -1)))) > 0
        # return GB to MB calculated                                               
        THEN (TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.value, ',', numbers.number), ',', -1)) + 0.00) * 1024
        # return MB value                                  
        ELSE TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.value, ',', numbers.number), ',', -1)) + 0.00                        
      END BETWEEN 512 AND (2 * 1024)
```

**Result**

```
| id    | content_id | group_id | value            | tag        | MB_calculated |
| ----- | ---------- | -------- | ---------------- | ---------- | ------------- |
| 12274 | 251        | 5        | 4 GB, 512 MB RAM | 512 MB RAM | 512           |
| 12323 | 252        | 5        | 32 GB, 2 GB RAM  | 2 GB RAM   | 2048          |
| 12372 | 253        | 5        | 8 GB, 2 GB RAM   | 2 GB RAM   | 2048          |
| 12421 | 254        | 5        | 8 GB, 1 GB RAM   | 1 GB RAM   | 1024          |
| 12470 | 255        | 5        | 8 GB, 1 GB RAM   | 1 GB RAM   | 1024          |
| 12519 | 256        | 5        | 4 GB, 512 MB RAM | 512 MB RAM | 512           |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9M4rKgL83TrCpNZDsHGBhC/0)

Comment: Now we need to get a number out of it, and perform a comparison. It's going to be ugly!

Comment: indeed @LightnessRacesinOrbit you also would have to convert the MB to GB, getting the number is not the problem.

Comment: If the OP be using MySQL 8+, then regex is the way to go.

Comment: Getting the number requires further parsing, i.e. the answer is incomplete.

Comment: *"Getting the number requires further parsing, i.e. the answer is incomplete."* @LightnessRacesinOrbit i believe this answer should be it as i needed to eat between thats when the first answer was a bit incomplete, but yes it's very ugly..